# Allow 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' from laravel as backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel, api

I have a laravel application in which a build my api
and i want to use react js on my front-end using the api from my laravel.

but when ever I tried calling the api from my react-app i get this error from my console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://magicsender.alresia.com/api/v1/auth/login' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

i am just stock here because I have browsed all search engine I couldn't find the right answer to my question.

Here is my code

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import AuthContext from "../../app/context/AuthProvider";

import axios from '../../app/api/axios';
const LOGIN_URL = '/auth/login';

const Login = () => {
const { setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
const userRef = useRef();
const errRef = useRef();

const [user, setUser] = useState('');
const [pwd, setPwd] = useState('');
const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('');
const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    userRef.current.focus();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    setErrMsg('');
}, [user, pwd])

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL,
            JSON.stringify({ user, pwd }),
            {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                withCredentials: true
            }
        );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response?.data));
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        const accessToken = response?.data?.accessToken;
        const roles = response?.data?.roles;
        setAuth({ user, pwd, roles, accessToken });
        setUser('');
        setPwd('');
        setSuccess(true);
    } catch (err) {
        if (!err?.response) {
            setErrMsg('No Server Response');
        } else if (err.response?.status === 400) {
            setErrMsg('Missing Username or Password');
        } else if (err.response?.status === 401) {
            setErrMsg('Unauthorized');
        } else {
            setErrMsg('Login Failed');
        }
        errRef.current.focus();
    }
}

return (
    <>
        {success ? (
            <section>
                <h1>You are logged in!</h1>
                <br />
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Go to Home</a>
                </p>
            </section>
        ) : (
            <section>
                <p ref={errRef} className={errMsg ? "errmsg" : "offscreen"} aria-live="assertive">{errMsg}</p>
                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="username"
                        ref={userRef}
                        autoComplete="off"
                        onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
                        value={user}
                        required
                    />

                    <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        onChange={(e) => setPwd(e.target.value)}
                        value={pwd}
                        required
                    />
                    <button>Sign In</button>
                </form>
                <p>
                    Need an Account?<br />
                    <span className="line">
                        {/*put router link here*/}
                        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </section>
        )}
    </>
 )
}
export default Login
```

Here is the code in ../../app/api/axios

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://magicsender.alresia.com/api/v1'
});
```

Please any help will be much appreciated
I am not too good in NodeJS but I've been using laravel for a long time

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#cors.

Comment: Read the error message - _"The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute."_ Did you try without `withCredentials: true`?

Answer (score 1):

make sure in your laravel config>cors.php supports_credentials is set to true.

```js
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

in your .env file set your session driver to cookie

```js
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

and in your axios headers
you can use install and use js-cookie to get XSRF-TOKEN
and set withCredentials to true

```js
import cookie from 'js-cookie'
let token = cookie.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://magicsender.alresia.com/api/v1',
    'Authorization': `${token}`,
    withCredentials: true
})
```